# How to create a client to connect to port 443, with an opening statement that indicates it should switch protocols?

Tags: ssl, tcp, https

If I connect to port 80 and send the text `FOOBAR`, then the HTTP server will immediately reject. Since I know this is always a non-HTTP request, I can intercept requests that start with `FOOBAR` and send them to my own custom TCP service. Thus I can extend my use of port 80 to add a non-HTTP server, without interrupting the real HTTP traffic.

I know how to use port 80, because I am good to go so long as I do not collide with one of the existing method names (`GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, etc). I can make my own (for example `BAZ`) with no collision risk.

What if I want to use port 443? What should I look for to create an opening statement that will not result in collision?

Comment: I recently wrote an FTP server, and in FTP the part about TLS was implemented by first connecting using plaintext, then asking the server to start an SSL/TLS handshake using the AUTH command. That way both encrypted/plaintext connections could be made on the same port. Could the HTTP protocol have something similar?

Comment: @sautuon, I do not want to open a TLS connection first, and I cannot open the FOOBAR connection first, so the FTP-style solution is unfortunately not sufficient. If it was HTTP first then that would be OK, but TLS has the encryption layer making it less practical.